# MacBook doesn't boot on MacOS (only on Windows)

Tags: macos, startup

I have a Apple MacBook Pro 13 i5 16/512GB Grey(MWP42D/A).
A few days ago, I was struggling to get my Samsung Portable SSD T7 Touch to work with it, so I reinstalled the Samsung encryption software and tried to restart the MacBook Pro.
Since then my MacBook never booted on MacOS again.

Things I have tried so far that didn't work:

- Recovery mode (Doesn't show the options and keeps restarting and showing a black screen)
- Recovery mode via Internet (Keeps restarting and asking for my WLAN password...)
- Booting from a bootable USB drive with Sonoma (Keeps restarting and showing a black screen)
- Power cycle (10 seconds holding the power button)
- Safe mode boot (Nothing happens, keep restarting and showing a black screen)
- Reset the PRAM / NVRAM
- Disk utility via my Windows partition (No errors found)
- Target mode through a different MacBook (Cannot get access to my data even after typing in my password)

I doubt it is a hardware issue, because I can perfectly boot and use it on Windows.
What options do I still have left before paying 600 bucks to Apple to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried booting (normally, to recovery, to internet recovery) with all external devices disconnected? Only other thing I can suggest is to wipe the entire drive and start again, but I can understand you being reluctant to do that as it could mean losing access to Windows as well as macOS.

Comment: You might be able to use Windows to put the Sonoma installer volume on the internal drive.

Comment: Two questions - when you say “ because I can perfectly boot and use it on Windows” is it the Mac hardware? when you say “ reinstalled the software” what software was that and to which OS and device was it installed? I would love to see the `diskutil list` and `gpt` output from the problematic Mac as seen by another Mac via target disk mode. Perhaps we can fill in some of the blanks.

Comment: Two more questions - what macOS version do you want running on the problem Mac and what version is on the Mac using target disk mode.

Comment: @bmike Software meant was the Samsung Encryption Software

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, when it's "Booting from a bootable USB drive with Sonoma", that it's actually booting the Sonoma installation USB?  I ask because you say "I can perfectly boot and use it on Windows", which sort of implies that you are doing a Windows Boot Camp dual boot, amirite, or if not, just how are you booting into Windows?  If so, you are going through the Mac boot process, and yet you say "Recovery mode (Doesn't show the options and keeps restarting and showing a black screen)" ...?

My point is that the installation USBs are "blessed" drives that essentially boot into Recovery mode using an image completely on the USB, and if your hardware is well enough to run Windows, it almost surely could run macOS.

Comment: Also, that "reinstalled the software " has me worried.  Which software?  If you reinstalled macOS, and you are trying to boot into macOS using the Windows boot loader, .... I'm not sure Sonoma will let you do that, because of a possible issue at the TPM/pre-pre-boot level.

Comment: I meant the Samsung Encryption Software which comes with the external hard disk

Comment: Im pretty sure that the bootloader should not be of concern. Its almost impossible to modify an intel Mac's bios, and the bios can boot every OS compatible with the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

First, boot into windows and flash a USB drive with an Ubuntu installer disk: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media. Then shut down the Mac and plug in the USB drive.

Hold down ALT when you boot up the mac. Take a picture after it comes to a screen like this and send an imgur link here.[image]

If it shows up, and the USB drive also shows up, then boot into ubuntu and check if it boots. I will follow up on what to do depending on how it goes - likely the best option is wiping the entire disk and reinstalling macos, but don't do this immediately..